# How can I put $group condition to $match?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have simple aggregate query in mongo:

```
    collection.aggregate([
        { 
            $match: { owner } 
        }, { 
            $group: { 
                _id: "$email" ,
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ])
```

but in the result I need see emails with count great than 3.

How can I do this?

Comment: Add `{ $match: { count: { $gt: 3 } } }` to the **end** of the pipeline as well. You are allowed to do that.

Comment: Thanks! That work!